# Non-Uniform Multinomial/Binomial Distribution Repetition Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, asymptotics, approximation-theory

I am looking for an asymptotic upper bound or approximation on the probability that two i.i.d. multinomial ($n$,$\mathbf{p}$) with $Q$ categories are the same. Formally, I am looking for a way to bound the following:
$$\sum_{x_1+\ldots+x_Q=n}\binom{n}{x_1,\ldots,x_Q}^2 \left(\prod\limits_{i=1}^n p_i^{x_i}\right)^2$$

Or, the simple Binomial(n,p) version of the problem

$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2 p^{2i} (1-p)^{2(n-i)}$$

When the distribution is uniform, from Theorem 4 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.5028.pdf) (thanks to md5), the former becomes
$$\sum_{x_1+\ldots+x_Q=n}\binom{n}{x_1,\ldots,x_Q}^2 Q^{-2n} \sim Q^{Q/2}(4\pi n)^{(1-Q)/2}$$
and making simpler arguments, the latter becomes
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}^2 2^{-2n}&=\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}\\
&\le \frac{2\sqrt{\pi}}{e^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align*}
both diminishing with $n$.

I have tried the approach given in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.5028.pdf), but due to the asymmetry in the probabilities I could not obtain a fairly nice term, given in Eqn 5 in the linked paper. I tried entropy bounds as well, yet they gave me the trivial upper bound of 1.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I would guess you might perhaps want to investigate something proportional to $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$

Comment: ... for the binomial case

Comment: Agreed, my simulations tell me it is $O(n^{-1/2})$ in the Binomial scenario just like the uniform case, though I haven't investigated for different values of $p$. Thanks.